# how to add g++ support in toolchain

Tags: cross-compiling, buildroot, gnu-toolchain

I want to add support for g++ compiler in my toochain. I am building toolchain for powerpc platform.I googled about it and found that we have to add external toolchian in our existing toolchain.

I want to create this binary: CXX = powerpc-linux-uclibc-g++

I am using buildroot version 2010.02 and uClibc version 0.9.30.2 gcc version 4_3_4.
any suggetions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run make menuconfig in your buildroot system.  Under the toolchain heading select the g++ option.  Save off your changes and run make.

Comment: Well thanks JS3..it worked!
after make menuconfig these two flags are set in my config file
` BR2_GCC_CROSS_CXX=y
BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP=y`